# Change Netrw's browsing directory to Vim's current directory?

Tags: vim, netrw

While browsing in Netrw, how do I change Netrw's browsing directory to Vim's current directory?

Typing `cd` changes Vim's current directory to Netrw's browsing directory, but I want the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `:e .` in the `netrw` window to reset to your vim current directory.